# Simulating coin toss

Tags: r, loops

In the [New York Times yesterday](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/18/sunday-review/gamblers-scientists-and-the-mysterious-hot-hand.html?ref=opinion&_r=0) there was a reference to a paper essentially saying that the probability of 'heads' after a 'head' appears is not 0.5 (assuming a fair coin), challenging the "hot hand" myth. I want to prove it to myself.

Thus, I am working on coding a simulation of 7 coin tosses, and counting the number of heads after the first head, provided, naturally, that there is a first head at all.

I came up with the following lines of R code, but I'm still getting NA values, and would appreciate some help:

```
n <- 7              # number of tosses
p <- 0.5            # probability of heads
sims <- 100         # number of simulations

Freq_post_H <- 0    # frequency of 'head'-s after first 'head' 
    for(i in 1:sims){
        z <- rbinom(n, 1, p)
        if(sum(z==1)!=0){
        y <- which(z==1)[1]
        Freq_post_H[i] <- sum(z[(y+1):n])/length((y+1):n) 
        }else{
            next()
        }
    Freq_post_H
    }
Freq_post_H
```

What am I missing?

CONCLUSION: After the initial hiccups of mismatched variable names, both responses solve the question. One of the answers corrects problems in the initial code related to what happens with the last toss `(i + 1)` by introducing `min(y + 1, n)`, and corrects the basic misunderstanding of `next` within a loop generating `NA` for skipped iterations. So thank you (+1).

Critically, and the reason for this appended "conclusion" the second response addresses a more fundamental or conceptual problem: we want to calculate the fraction of H's that are preceded by a H, as opposed to `p(H)` in whatever number of tosses remain after a head has appeared, which will be 0.5 for a fair coin.

Comment: I don't understand why you simulate the first coin toss for this. Can't you simply do `rbinom(sims, 6, 0.5)`?

Comment: `Freq_post_H` is unaffected by the loop. Did you mean for the value to change somehow?

Comment: You may have to also account for the last toss being the first Heads. `z <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)` will produce NA since `(y+1)` will be `NA`.

Comment: In the [New York Times yesterday](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/18/sunday-review/gamblers-scientists-and-the-mysterious-hot-hand.html?ref=opinion&_r=0) there was a reference to a paper essentially saying that the probability of  'heads' after a 'head' appears is not 0.5 (assuming a fair coin), challenging the "hot hand" myth. I want to prove it to myself.

Comment: @PierreLafortune True. That invalidates the question. However, I was also getting NA's even when I had made the goofy mistake of not increasing the counting (i + 1) to eliminate the already actualized "Head".

Comment: You are not paying attention to the first comment. You create `Freq_post_H` but assign the simulation results to another variable `Prob_post_H[i]`

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune Just a transcription error... I initially called it Prob_post_H, but while writing the question I changed it without realizing I had left one of the lines as it was. The issue predated this typo.

Comment: If you sit at a table and had a heads results, the probability that the next toss is heads is exactly 50 % for a fair coin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simulation of what they did in the newspaper:

```
nsims <- 10000
k <- 4
set.seed(42)
sims <- replicate(nsims, {
  x <- sample(0:1, k, TRUE)
  #print(x)
  sum( # sum logical values, i.e. 0/1
   diff(x) == 0L & # is difference between consecutive values 0? 
     x[-1] == 1L ) / # and are these values heads? 
       sum(head(x, -1) == 1L) #divide by number of heads (without last toss)
})

mean(sims, na.rm = TRUE)  #NaN cases are samples without heads, i.e. 0/0
#[1] 0.4054715

k <- 7

sims <- replicate(nsims, {
  x <- sample(0:1, k, TRUE)
  #print(x)
  sum(diff(x) == 0L & x[-1] == 1L) / sum(head(x, -1) == 1L) 
})

mean(sims, na.rm = TRUE) 
#[1] 0.4289402
```

Comment: I think this probably makes sense. I have a dentist appointment, and have to run. I'll come back to it later. Could you please throw me a bonus and tell me what `diff(x) == 0L` is all about? I have no idea about the `L` or the `diff`. Thanks!

Comment: `diff` calculates the difference between elements of a vector. A number followed by `L` denotes an integer value (as opposed to a numeric/double).

Comment: Could you please tell me I'm English what success is doing? It's well over my head...

Comment: I've added some comments.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at "L" and now see the difference between integer and numeric, yet I don't fully comprehend why you needed to include it here. Also, Do you still think it's 50% even after your simulations, and reading the paper quoted by the NYT? It seems as though it's incredibly a bit lower than 0.5, isn't it?

Comment: You don't need the L, but it's always better to be explicit when comparing numbers. If you compare floating point numbers there could be trouble. It's really important to be aware about which (conditional) probability we are talking. If you already know that there was a "heads" result, the probability for another "heads" is exactly 50 %, because the past doesn't matter for a coin toss. But that's not what the newspaper's article is about.

Answer (score 1):

```
n <- 7              # number of tosses
p <- 0.5            # probability of heads
sims <- 100         # number of simulations

Prob_post_H <- 0    # frequency of 'head'-s after first 'head' 
    for(i in 1:sims){
        z <- rbinom(n, 1, p)
        if(sum(z==1) != 0){
        y <- which(z==1)[1]
        Prob_post_H[i] <- mean(z[min(y+1, n):n], na.rm=TRUE)
        }else{
            next()
        }
    }
mean(Prob_post_H,na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 0.495068
```

It looks like it's right around 50%. We can scale up to see more simulations.

```
sims <- 10000

mean(Prob_post_H,na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 0.5057866
```

Still around 50%.

Comment: Yes. That was my intention... Thank you!

Comment: I just ran your code by copying and pasting, but instead of doing the `mean` at the end, I simply print `Prob_post_H` ... and I do get NA's

Comment: NA's represent the skipped iterations.

Comment: I didn't know that, 'cause I never used the `next` command. This definitely takes care of the issue. Thank you.

Comment: `next` is not a function (well technically it is, but you don't need parentheses). It's also not needed since you could simply omit the `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

This is to simulate 100 fair coin tosses 30,000 times

```
counter <- 1 
coin <- sum(rbinom(100,1,0.5)) 
while(counter<30000){
  coin <- c(coin, sum(rbinom(100,1,0.5)))
  counter <- counter+1
}
```

Try these after running above variable

```
 hist(coin)
 str(coin)
 mean(coin)
 sd(coin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is some sample code in R to simulate a fair coin toss in R using the sample function.  You can modify it as you like to simulate any number of flips.  Since the outcome of flipping a coin is independent for each flip, the probability of a head or tail is always 0.5 for any given flip.  Over many coin flips the probability of at least half of the flips being heads (or tails) will converge to 0.5.  The probability that you get exactly half heads and half tails approaches 0.

```
n <- 7
count_heads <- 0
coin_flip <- sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE)
for(flip_i in 1:n)
{
  if(coin_flip[flip_i] == 1)
  {
    count_heads = count_heads + 1
  }
}
count_heads/n
```