# Hot Hand Fallacy: R Code to Reproduce Simulation

Tags: r, simulation, probability

BACKGROUND:

As a follow-up of my [preceding question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33215447/4089351), I would like to ask for help reproducing a more intricate result on the [original paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2627354) quoted by an [opinion column in The New York Times yesterday](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/18/sunday-review/gamblers-scientists-and-the-mysterious-hot-hand.html?ref=opinion&_r=0). In that paper originated in Milan and Alicante, an interesting reduction in the frequency by which a Head was followed by another head (~ 40%) was presented. The simulation in the SO question this morning was concordant after solved by @Roland.

QUESTION"

The question is how to code in R a simulation to reproduce the fraction of successes ("heads") in a coin toss that follow a sequence of successes (`k` successes) in short coin toss experiment (`n` tosses), as in the plot included below, which belongs to an article linked in the "background" part of the question.

[image]

Comment: Could you please update this question so it can be answered without 1) Reading a previous Stack Overflow question and 2) Reading a NY Times article (which is behind a paywall)? In particular, could you describe the experiment that leads to the figure you included?

Comment: @josilber Sorry about the paywall - didn't realize that. In thinking how to do it, can I ask you if you had problems pulling up the original research paper, which is linked independently?

Comment: Well, my main point is that readers of your question here should not need to read external resources to understand what you're asking (especially entire research papers!). Note that if the SSRN paper gets deleted, for instance, a future visitor to your question wouldn't understand what you were asking.

Comment: @josilber Your point is well taken. I just need to know before I reword it if you can get the original paper even if it is out of intellectual credit to the authors.

Comment: Yes I can access the SSRN paper.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution:

```
#' @param n An integer giving the number of trials
#' @param k An integer giving the prior-streak size.
#' @examples 
#' repeat_success(10,2)
#' repeat_success(100, 5)

repeat_success <- function(n,k) {
  path <- sample(c(1,0), size= n, replace= TRUE)
  successes <- which(path == 1)

  streaks <- rep(0, length(successes))
  for (i in 1:length(successes)) {
    j <- successes[i]
    if (j > k)
      streaks[i] <- ifelse(sum(path[(j-k):(j-1)]) == k, 1, 0)
  }
  return(list(successes= successes, frac_streaks= sum(streaks) / sum(path)))
}

R> repeat_success(10,2)
$successes
[1] 1 3 5 8 9

$frac_streaks
[1] 0
```

Obviously, you could set a seed for reproducibility. And clearly I haven't included error checking on the parameters.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the elements within the function... What is `path` designed to do? I haven't found documentation on it.

Comment: It's the realized permutation of successes and failures. Also, note that the denominator in the calculated fraction may not be exactly what you wanted. It wasn't clear to me.

Comment: When I type `path()` R complains that the function does not exist. Yet it does accept your code.